# Does $\Delta u=0$ for $u:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ imply that $u$ must be a hyperplane?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider a function $u$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$, such that $\Delta u=0$. Can we assume that the graph of $u:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ must be a hyperplane?

If that is true, then a lot of results of harmonic functions like regularity etc would become much easier to prove

Comment: "The graph of $u$ is a hyperplane" is equivalent to saying "$u$ is linear".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, consider the example $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ we see $\Delta u=0$ but plot the graph and you don't get a hyperplane in $\mathbf{R}^3$

Comment: haha yeah thought of that right after I posted the question

Comment: happens to all of us, asking questions is essential